# How can I avoid error Injection of autowired dependencies failed?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, autowired

I'm trying to add JpaRepository to my Spring MVC JPA project.

Right now with my configuration everything works great.  I have a simple model (based on a project by fruzenshtein, https://github.com/Fruzenshtein/spr-data).

```
Model: Shop
Service: ShopService
Controller: ShopController
```

For example in **ShopServiceImpl.java** I have just one method:

```
@Transactional
public List<Shop> getAll() {

    List<Shop> result = em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Shop s", Shop.class).getResultList();
    return result;
}
```

and in ShopController.java I add my @Autowired

```
@Autowired
private ShopService shopSvc;
```

At this point everythings ok.

**Well, I want to add my own repository like this:**

```
@Repository 
public interface ShopRepository extends JpaRepository<Shop, Integer> {
}
```

and add @Autowired in ShopServiceImpl.java

```
@Autowired
private ShopRepository shopRepository;
```

and I get this error:

```
**org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:Error creating bean with name 'shopServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.jpa.repository.ShopRepository 
org.jpa.service.ShopServiceImpl.shopRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shopRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null**
```

I know this is an old issue posted before, but after two weeks trying to fix this error (I think I had read all forum in stackoverflow) I dediced to post my question/problem with my own code waiting for a possible solution

**This is my code:**

Model:

```
public class Shop {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "employees_number")
    private Integer emplNumber;

    // Constructor obligatorio
    public Shop() {
    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Integer getEmplNumber() {
        return emplNumber;
    }
    public void setEmplNumber(Integer emplNumber) {
        this.emplNumber = emplNumber;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository 
public interface ShopRepository extends JpaRepository<Shop, Integer> {
    List<Shop> findByShopId(Long userId);
}
```

ShopService:

```
public interface ShopService {
    public List<Shop> findAll();
}
```

ShopServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class ShopServiceImpl implements ShopService {
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ShopServiceImpl.class);
    @Autowired
    private ShopRepository shopRepository;
    // An EntityManager will be automatically injected from EntityManagerFactory

    // setup on spring-context.xml
    // @PersistenceContext
    // private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public List<Shop> findAll() {
        return shopRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

ShopController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/shop")
public class ShopController {
    @Autowired
    private ShopServiceImpl shopService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView shopListPage() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("shop-list");
        List<Shop> shopList = shopService.findAll();
        if (shopList != null) {
            mav.addObject("shopList", shopList);
            return mav;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>jpa-hibernate</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <description>
        </description>
        <display-name>jpa</display-name>
        <servlet-name>jpa</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jpa</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

jpa-servlet.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx">

    <!-- http://www.journaldev.com/7655/spring-orm-example-with-jpa-hibernate-transactions -->
    <!-- http://gordondickens.com/wordpress/2011/08/01/simpler-jpa-with-spring-data-jpa/ -->
    <!-- <context:annotation-config /> -->
    <!-- <beans:bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" 
        /> -->


   <!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered 
        as Spring beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.jpa" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.jpa.repository" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.jpa.service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.jpa.controller" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.jpa.model" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
     <beans:bean
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>


    <!-- DataSource para Microsoft Sql Server 2005 -->
    <beans:bean id="dataSource" name="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName"
            value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        p:packagesToScan="org.jpa" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
        <beans:property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <beans:property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                <beans:property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Transactions -->
    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <!-- <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> -->


    <!-- JPA -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="org.jpa.repository" />
        <!-- <jpa:repositories base-package="org.jpa.repository" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" 
        transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" /> -->
    <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes e.g: @Autowired -->
</beans:beans>
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>jpa-repository</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpa-repository</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>3.6.0.Final</hibernate.version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">


    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <!-- <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA"> -->
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
            <!-- Show and print nice SQL on stdout -->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" 
                /> -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
        </properties>


    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Added entire stacktrace log:

```
   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shopController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.jpa.service.ShopServiceImpl org.jpa.controller.ShopController.shopService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shopServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.jpa.repository.ShopRepository org.jpa.service.ShopServiceImpl.shopRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shopRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:211)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1029)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:862)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4013)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4357)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1083)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:789)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1083)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:478)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:480)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:2313)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:556)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:287)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:425)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.jpa.service.ShopServiceImpl org.jpa.controller.ShopController.shopService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shopServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.jpa.repository.ShopRepository org.jpa.service.ShopServiceImpl.shopRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shopRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:92)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
        ... 34 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shopServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.jpa.repository.ShopRepository org.jpa.service.ShopServiceImpl.shopRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shopRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:871)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:813)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:730)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:485)
        ... 36 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.jpa.repository.ShopRepository org.jpa.service.ShopServiceImpl.shopRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shopRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:92)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
        ... 47 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shopRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1442)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:871)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:813)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:730)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:485)
        ... 49 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:123)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.<init>(SimpleJpaRepository.java:74)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:94)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:69)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:146)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:120)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:39)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
        ... 57 more

    2016-02-15 12:07:39 StandardContext[/jpa-hibernate]El Servlet /jpa-hibernate lanzó excepción de load()
    javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() para servlet jpa lanzó excepción
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1071)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:862)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4013)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4357)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1083)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:789)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1083)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:478)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:480)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:2313)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:556)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    ----- Root Cause -----
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shopController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.jpa.service.ShopServiceImpl org.jpa.controller.ShopController.shopService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shopServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.jpa.repository.ShopRepository org.jpa.service.ShopServiceImpl.shopRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shopRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null
```

Added code to github:
https://github.com/elecdesa/jpa-repository/

Thanks

Comment: Post entire stacktrace.

Comment: do you have the right package included in Jpa:repository tag?

Comment: i guess so. Package is org.jpa.repository and interface there is: ShopRepository.java. I use the tag <jpa:repositories base-package="org.jpa.repository" />

Comment: Note that you should autowire on interfaces generally speaking, not on implementations. `@Autowired private ShopServiceImpl shopService;` should be changed to `@Autowired private ShopService shopService;`

Comment: I get the same error, just change the name:org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shopController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested ex...........

Comment: I do note that you're using an ancient version of Spring; is there a particular reason for this?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the enviroment is old (tomcat 5.0.16 + jdk1.5.0_11) and I can't change it. That's the reason why I'm doing like that. As I said before, the project works without Repository but using Repository avoid lines of code..

Answer (score 1):

On your repository, you listed a method `findByShopId`, but your class has no `shopId` property. Remove the declaration and just use `find`.

(Also, for any new Spring projects, use Boot; it dramatically cuts down on the boilerplate configuration. Additionally, use constructor injection instead of field injection whenever possible.)

Comment: Removed findByShopId from ShopRepository. Added to ServiceImpl shopRepository.findAll()

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved the problem. Making some changes and it works.

code in github: https://github.com/elecdesa/jpa-repository/

Thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried moving the @Repository annotation from the ShopRepository interface to the actual class that implements it?

Comment: There is no implementing class; it's a dynamic proxy.